# How to install dual boot system CentOS & Windows?

Tags: linux, centos, windows, dual-boot

I want to install a dual boot system on a single hdd with EFI support (or without). CentOS 7 as the primary operating system and Windows 10 as the second system mostly for gaming. What is the *canonical* algorithm or sequence of actions for this?

If I disable EFI support in the BIOS of my motherboard, then I can split HDD into four primary MBR partitions: swap, root, ntfs, home - is this correct?

If I enable EFI support, then I need a fifth EFI partition, but there may be only four of them. Should I use GPT or it is better to use a swap file instead of a separate partition?

Comment: If planning on using Windows, that controls partitioning. Windows only boots in UEFI mode from gpt partitioned drives and only in old BIOS mode from MBR(msdos) partitioned drives. BIOS & UEFI Windows partitions, note system has totally different format  & meaning between BIOS & UEFI
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898504%28v=vs.85%29.aspx & 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations

Answer (score 0):

I was going to put this in comments but I think there's a bit too much information for that.

The first part of your question, asking for steps to install a dual boot system can be answered very easily by doing a simple google search.

With regard to partitioning.  You don't need multiple partitions.  These days it's quite justifiable to have only one for a desktop environment.  Swap can be a swap file with no side effects.  Root (`/`) and home (`/home/`)  don't need to be separate.  Different people have different reasons for their partitioning schemes so it's entirely your choice.

MBR is not limited to 4 partitions.  But with "logical partitions" MBR will support more.

If you have the choice use GPT with EFI.  Don't use "legacy boot" (disabling EFI) and MBR is generally considered legacy now.  One of the best reasons to use EFI is that it allows boot loaders for your multiple operating systems can sit side by side.